# Macbook Pro 2010 Ethernet Jumbo Frame(9k MTU) Support?

Tags: networking, macbook-pro, mtu

Has anyone been able to use jumbo frame support on their 2010 Macbook Pros?  This is kind of negative news here, but I am seeing many reports that this is not available anymore due to Apple's choice of network card in the new machines.  I cannot set my MTU speed over 1500 on my new 2010 MBP i7, but my old early 2008 MBP (Core2) has the 9000 MTU setting for use.  Everything I have is setup to use jumbo frames and I thought apple kept that feature in their "pro" lineup.  It sounds like the Mac Pro still has it.  Did they decide to use a chip set that doesn't support it?  I am trying to pinpoint some solid chip set numbers and the feature support.  Maybe they just need to update the drivers?

Is there some more official information about this feature? This might seem minor, but this is really frustrating if apple removed this feature from their pro laptop line.  From what I have read so far, it sounds like I am not alone in my frustrations with this.

- http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=12258067
- http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=12130158

Anyone have any experience or further knowledge about this issue ... beyond typing my question into google and giving the top 5 results as answers?

Comment: Looks like Jumbo frames are a no go...http://forums.creativecow.net/readpost/8/1087489

Answer (score 1):

I am no Mac user, but I did find this article where the person used 2 gigabit USB adapters to get the full bandwidth of jumbo frames, it's sort of a work around.

http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/8/1084302

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported by the Broadcom 5764 chip, sadly. See http://www.broadcom.com/collateral/pg/5764M-PG100-R.pdf for more details.